# my app electron doesn't recognize data from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, electron

We have an application in html, js, css compiled by electron and we use firebase to store data, and render it on frontend but we store the data in localstorage and then display it in frontend, the problem is that in some laptops the data from local storage is not recognized and throw an error that it is not defined.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'encabezado' of null
```

Comment: And you are trying to access the LocalStorage API _only_ from the renderer process(es), correct?  LocalStorage is not available to the main process (or other non-renderer processes).

Comment: "Some laptops" -- you should know the operating system is most important here as Electron on different constraints based upon OS. What is the difference SW wise between the presumable laptops that work and some that don't?

Comment: The problem occurs in laptops with Windows but the strange thing is that the app works fine on a laptop but in the others not.